# Pytorch 'CUDA out of memory' with only one training batch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am currently trying to implement a network similar to U-Net and am having some weird issues with loading my data to the GPU.
Specifically, when I load my model to the GPU with

```
model = CNN(NUM_LAYERS)
model.to(DEVICE)
```

the memory usage on the GPU rises to `1063 MiB`. This tells me that my model is roughly one GB in memory. So far so good. Then, with

```
inst = (iter(dataloader)).__next__()
input_tensor = inst[0].to(DEVICE, dtype=torch.float)
```

I load one batch of training data to the GPU. The total GPU memory usage rises to `1093 MiB`, which seems about right and tells me that the batch of 8 training images is about 30MB in size. Now I execute

```
output = model(input_tensor)
```

and the memory usage shoots up to `21123 MiB`! And if I change the batch size to something bigger, say 16, I get 
`CUDA out of memory (GPU 1; 31.72 GiB total capacity; 29.91 GiB already allocated; 359.75 MiB free; 402.84 MiB cached)`.

I've tried to figure out what exactly happens when I feed a tensor to the model, but I can't seem to work out why the GPU memory would suddenly increase like that. Am I correct in saying that at this point I should have exactly three things on the GPU: the model, the input tensor and the output tensor?

The dataloader , by the way looks like this:

```
class AsyncCNNData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, list_paths, resize_dims=None, transform=None, device='cpu'):
        'Initialization'
        super().__init__()

        self.list_paths = list_paths
        self.transform = transform
        self.to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
        self.device = device
        self.resize_dims=resize_dims

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the total number of samples'
        return len(self.list_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generates one sample of data'
        # Select sample
        sample_path = self.list_paths[index]

        # Load data and get label
        fs = cv.FileStorage(sample_path, cv.FILE_STORAGE_READ)

        cti_list = []
        for i in range(0, NUM_LAYERS, 1):
            img_name = "layer_{0:03d}".format(i)
            img = (fs.getNode(img_name)).mat()
            diff = np.subtract(self.resize_dims, img.shape)/2
            img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, int(diff[0]), int(diff[0]), int(diff[1]), int(diff[1]), cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, 1)
            cti_list.append(img)

        input_tensor = np.stack(cti_list)
        input_tensor = input_tensor[np.newaxis, :, :, :]

        img = (fs.getNode("frame")).mat()
        diff = np.subtract(self.resize_dims, img.shape)/2
        img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, int(diff[0]), int(diff[0]), int(diff[1]), int(diff[1]), cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, 1)
        img = img[:, :, np.newaxis]
        output_tensor = self.to_tensor(img)

        if self.transform != None:
            input_tensor = self.transform(input_tensor)
        else:
            input_tensor = torch.from_numpy(input_tensor)

        return input_tensor, output_tensor, sample_path
```

and

```
yaml_files = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH).values.flatten().tolist()
data = AsyncCNNData(yaml_files, device=DEVICE, resize_dims=RESIZE)

train_size = int(len(data)*TRAIN_RATIO)
data_train, data_test = random_split(data, [train_size, len(data)-train_size])
dataloader = DataLoader(data_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
```

Many many thanks!

Comment: what GPU are you using? you have 32 GB memory in GPU!! still not enough? did you check the sizes of the input and output tensors?

Comment: I'm using a Quadro GV100. Yeah, I did check, they are entirely what I'd expect - 8x1x16x240x180 for the input and 1x1x1x240x180 for the output (so that's Batch Size, Channels, Depth, Height, Width). They are float tensors, so certainly shouldn't be using 21GB of memory...I'm thinking maybe pytorch is saving intermediate results or something, maybe someone could confirm or debunk this...?